# Pulling picklist options from a multi-value field

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, string

I am currently pulling select options for a multi-value picklist from a query which gathers field values from all of the child records from a certain __r relationship of an account.

I would like to do the same type of thing, but by querying a record and using the values of one of its multi-value fields as the select options of a picklist.

Here is part of my current working code which queries all of the Subsidiaries of an Account and then uses the names of all of those Subsidiaries as choices in a picklist by referring to !items :

```
    public list<selectoption> getitems()
        {
        accountid=contract.Account__c;


        List<selectoption> options= new list<selectoption>();
            if(accountid != null)
            {
            account a =[select name , (select name from Subsidiaries_and_Brands__r) from account where id =:accountid];
                for(SubsidiariesAndBrands__c s : a.Subsidiaries_and_Brands__r)
                    {
                    options.add(new SelectOption(s.name,s.name));
                    }
            }
            else
            options.add(new SelectOption('None','None'));
            return options;
        }


}
```

Instead of gathering the field value from multiple records I would like to just query a single record and get the values from multiple value field from the record and turn them into the picklist options. The record I will be querying is the parent record of the record I will currently be in. The lookup field which I would like to use as the query key is Contract_Title__c. The relationship name with the object which it will be pulling the field values from is Contract_Title__r.

So I guess I need something like this

```
public string contractid{get;set;}

public list<selectoption> getitems()
            {
            contractid=contract.Contract_Title__c;

contract = [SELECT Subsidiaries_On_Contract__c FROM Contract_Overview__c where Contract_Overview__c.id=:contractid];
```

But I don't know how to properly build the list from that. I feel like I'm really close.

Can anybody help me on this ? I really appreciate any help I can get for this. Thank you very much for your time.

UPDATED ATTEMPT AT SOLUTION :

```
String[] picklistlines =new String[]{};
String selectedMulPickKeyTech{get;set;} 

public string contractid{get;set;}

public list<selectoption> getitems()
            {
            contractid=contract.Contract_Title__c;

contract = [SELECT Subsidiaries_On_Contract__c FROM Contract_Overview__c where Contract_Overview__c.id=:contractid];

selectedMulPickKeyTech=contract.Subsidiaries_On_Contract__c;



picklistlines = selectedMulPickKeyTech.split('\n');
```

I don't know if that SOQL query will work because I don't know if I have properly identified contract before trying to use it in it.

I also don't know how to properly build the selectedMulPickKeyTech.I know I need a For statement in there, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for your response jkraybill. Right now what I am mostly struggling with how to put the results of the multivalue field into a list. I know it will need to be a For statement to pull each value of the field into the list. I'm also not sure my query will work. I'm trying to pull the Subsidiaries_On_Contract field from the Contract_Overview_c record which is related to this record through a Contract_Title__r relationship. I'm not sure of the proper query for that. Thank you very much for all of your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Multi-value picklist fields have their values stored as a semi-colon-delimited list. So if you just do a String split over semi-colons on the resulting value you'll get a list.

Comment: Yes, I knew I had to use a String somehow but I don't exactly know how. Can you show me the proper syntax for it and the query ? Thank you very much jkraybill.

Comment: String.split is documented here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm and there are many examples of code and queries online.

Comment: He already has a list of his picklist items. He doesn't need to do a split. A join of all the elements in his list is what's required.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you simply need to build the list. You already seem to have all of the elements you need to create the string. However, you may have some extra whitespace that you'll want to remove. If that's the case, you'll need to create a for loop and do some string operations on it to remove the extra white space. jkraybill pointed you to right section of the Apex docs for the calls to use. If you don't need to remove whitespace, its a very simple call to join the elements from a single list into a single string.

Your code should look something like this:

```
String piklst = String.join(contract, ';');
```

I'm not certain if you'll need to or not (will leave it to you to check), but you may need to escape the semicolon with a `'\'` as in `'\;'`. Some characters require that and some don't. I never can remember which ones do. Essentially, you're using a Regular Expression to do the join.

**Edited for code updates Below**

After looking at your updated code, as relates to the following line:

```
 picklistlines = selectedMulPickKeyTech.split('\n');
```

Its not clear to me why you've added new line separators `('\n')` when picklists are normally separated by semicolons. Is this a particular requirement of your VF page mark-up code? It seems as though you've been pointed in a particular direction by several very experienced and knowledgeable programmers in this forum, yet have chosen to go in a very different direction.

Regarding the SOQL query questions, if you're not certain about a SOQL query, I highly recommend you install Force.com Explorer or Ajax Tools and use the included Query Builder Tools in either of those utilities. I think you'll find both of them quite helpful.

I don't know that there's any additional help I can provide you. I've provided a clear example of how to join a list into a single string, including how to add the separator of your choice; something that's clearly explained in the documentation you've been pointed to. Some time spent doing diagnostics by adding a system.debug statement to test if its working for you is about all I can suggest (if you know the number of values, you can add that as a verification per the example in the docs). The same suggestion would apply to your SOQL queries (verifying them with known data).

If this response provided the answer to your question, it would be helpful to others if you marked it as such.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I know they're elementary questions but I'm only able to piece together certain elements of a solution through my reading, but now I'm trying to put it all together. I added another piece of code to my original post which shows where I'm at right now. I think I'm pretty close, but I think I have a couple key parts to solve. If you feel like looking at it I'd really appreciate it. Either way, thanks a lot for your help.